# VC++ Windows form Switch Back to Parent Window

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am unable to go back to previous window, the code of MyForm.h

```
private: System::Void nBSMeritCalculatorToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    this->Hide();
    MyForm1 ^ form = gcnew MyForm1;
    form->ShowDialog();
}
```

I included `MyForm1.h`,

Now when I do the same with `MyForm1.h` Menu item that switches back, I get a compiler error saying that `MyForm1` Was not declared(in `MyForm.h`)

The code of MyForm1.h (after including `MyForm.h`) is,

```
this->Hide();
    MyForm ^ form = gcnew MyForm;
    form->ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Creating a *new* form will not switch you back to the parent window.

Comment: I see, anyways, then put it this way, I want to go back to MyForm, by hiding or closing MyForm1.

Comment: come on answer it, someone!

Comment: You have a circular dependency between .h files.  MyForm.h includes MyForm1.h and MyForm1.h includes MyForm.h.  That cannot work.  You have to do the C++ dance with incomplete types and moving code into a .cpp file that #includes the declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Hans Passant said was completely true, so what I did was that I showed back the original window after the second form was closed, so it worked.(I didn't need to include MyForm1.h(Second form)).